# Why API can't retrive body of POST from React Client?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, post, fetch-api

The code for API on Backend with express.js

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()
var port = 5000;

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true})
app.use(urlencodedParser);

app.get('/', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
  console.log( req.body );
  res.send('welcome, Get is working')
})

app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
  console.log( req.body );
  res.send('welcome, Post is working...\n' + req.body.name)
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`))
```

React Code on Client Side

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { apiResponse: "" };
        console.log('constructor called');
    }

    callAPI() {
        console.log('callAPI called');

        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('name', 'myname');
        fetch(
          "/", {
            body: formData,
            method: 'post',
            header: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }   
          }   
        )   
            .then(res => res.text())
            .then(data => this.setState({ apiResponse: data })) 
    }   

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('componentDidMount called');
        this.callAPI();
    }   

    render() {
        console.log('render called');
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                    <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
                </header>
                <p className="App-intro">{this.state.apiResponse}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "my_react_app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5"
  },  
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },  
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

Browser shows:

> "welcome, Post is working... undefined"

and "console.log in api" shows no body, just "{}" only.

When I type the command `curl -d "name=myname" http://localhost:5000`, client terminal shows "welcome, Post is working..." and "console.log in api" shows "{ name: 'myname' }". Seems that it works properly.

I think there is no problem on API side at Backend.
But it can't be figured out what is wrong on client side.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set contentType multipart/form-data

```
 header: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
```

Comment: 'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data' doesn't work either.